# Shell Command to List VERSIONS of HTTP Modules in Apache 2.x

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

I have not found a **way to list the *versions* of the available Apache 2.x modules**, at least in CentOS 6.x. I believe it's possible to issue the following (pseudo code):

```
find /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/ -type f | while read ln; [...] ; done | rpm -qa $ln
```

The section ([...]) removes the first 25 characters and the last 3 of every $ln, then pipes it into `rpm`. This can be done via sed, awk or just bash. There are only a dozen or so lines to process, so **I am not looking for the most efficient way to accomplish this, just something that works.**.

Sample input:

```
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_authz_default.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_fcgid.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_log_config.so
```

Comment: try moving the `; done` to after your call to `rpm`. Note that in your current code, only the last value assigned to `$ln` will ever be presented to `rpm`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following:

```
find /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/ -type f | xargs -n1 rpm -qf | sort -u
```